# If Tachanun is optional to recite, why is it looked down upon when its omitted on a weekday?

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, tachanun

During Shacharis, due to time constraints i often only just recite Vidui, and jump to Ashrei 145, Lamenatzeach 20, Uva letzion, and Aleinu - al tirah. I do recite the full Vidui/Tachanun at Mincha though due to it being a shorter tefillah. Is that ok to do or not since Tachanun is optional. And since i daven alone at home i don't do nefillas apayim anyway. It seems to be looked down upon when one omits it on a weekday when it should be recited, but since it's optional and more private than publicly recited, what is wrong if one chooses not to recite it?

Comment: What makes you say it's optional

Comment: What do you mean by "optional"

Comment: I heard its optional/voluntary to recite. Alotta articles etc online seem to claim that as well from this Rav Natronai Gaon (quoted in Tur, Orach Chaim 131) states that Tachanun is only optional." It seems to very much used on other websites as well as a reference for it being optional.

Comment: Do you see why "If it is optional why is it bad to skip?" is a more confusing form of the question "how important is it?" If you don't know how obligatory something is, just ask.

Comment: "Optional" is an English word that is sometimes used to translate the Hebrew רשות but as with any translation it can lose nuance. Sometime רשות is used in contrast to חובה to specifically indicate a lower level of obligation.

Comment: How important is it to recite Tachanun ? i see alotta sources too online that say when one's short on time for Shacharis to mainly recite Ashrei 145, Lamnatzeach yaancha and uva letzion not mentioning Tachanun, but same time it is held as a very special tefillah. So if that's so, why is it omitted when time is short ? one would think it would be in there as well. I have nothing against Tachanun, i love reciting it but my mornings are short, and most of the time i have to omit it by making due with just reciting Vidui.

Comment: Ohhh i see, Ashaynem Dank for clearing that up for me Double AA.

Comment: I'd advise someone to prefer tachanun to uva letzion but that's just me. Don't trust everything you read online, and remember apparent online majorities can be misleading. And also I'm just a random guy here so don't trust me either even about that.

Comment: Tachanun being optional is a big claim to make

Comment: Maariv is also called רשות, but it's hardly considered optional today.

Comment: @shmosel or ever.

Comment: Maariv is absolutely not a rishus. Look at brachos 27b. Making this claim led to Rebbi Yehoshua being put in cherem.